# I am attempting to show myself the value from my firebase database using javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am unfamiliar with the technical terms but what I wish to get the value of the child **CanOrder** and display it in a simple `window.alert`. This code should trigger when I press a button but nothing shows up.

```
    function toggleOrder(){
   var location = firebase.database().ref();
   var ref = location.child("/MyCanteen/Schools/Cross&Passion/CanOrder?:");
   ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
   snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    window.alert(child.val());
  });
      }
   );
}
```

I have edited the code, this still returns nothing, The function is trigged with an onclick event from my button. `onclick ="toggleOrder()"`

Comment: "_This code should trigger when I press a button_" Can you show us where you attached this function to an onClick listener? What you have posted is just a function and won't do anything by itself.

Comment: Note that the function you're showing adds the event handler, nothing else. So if you call this from a button click, nothing's going to appear to happen.

Comment: What would be a possible solution?

Comment: Attach the function to the onclick listener when the page loads, not when the button is clicked. Just think about the order things should happen and make the code match.

Answer (score 0):

To better answer this, it would be ideal if we knew the structure of the data and whether *CanOrder* has a single value or a collection of child nodes within. Assuming that theres only a value at this node, the below code should work for you.

HTML example for calling the function.

```
 <html>
     <body>
         <button id="myButton" value="Get Can Data" onclick="toggleOrder()">
     </body>
</html>
```

Javascript for getting the data and triggering the alert.

```
 function toggleOrder(){
      var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("/MyCanteen/Schools/Cross&Passion/CanOrder/");

      ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
          var canOrderValue = snapshot.val();
          alert("Here is your value: " + canOrderValue);
      });
}
```